# Attempting to set up firebase and firestore with electron

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, electron

I wish to set up a firestore in order to run a simple global chat application. I currently have a main.js file with the following;

```
// Electron code above removed.

const fireapp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

// Get a Firestore instance
let firestore = firebase.firestore();

// Reference to the 'messages' collection
const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages')

// Submit message to Firestore
messageForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault() // prevent page reload on form submission

  const message = messageInput.value
  if (!message || message.length < 2) { return } 
  messageInput.value = '' // clear the input field after sending the message

  // Append the sent message to the console body
  const sentMessage = document.createElement('p')
  sentMessage.textContent = `YOU > ${message}`
  sentMessage.classList.add('sent-message')
  consoleBody.appendChild(sentMessage)
  consoleBody.scrollTop = consoleBody.scrollHeight

  // Save message to Firestore
  messagesRef.add({
    sender: 'YOU',
    text: message
  })
})

// Listen for new messages in Firestore
messagesRef.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const message = doc.data()

    // Append the received message to the console body
    const receivedMessage = document.createElement('p')
    receivedMessage.textContent = `${message.sender} > ${message.text}`
    consoleBody.appendChild(receivedMessage)
    consoleBody.scrollTop = consoleBody.scrollHeight
  })
})
```

Executing this resulted in the error
"firebase.firestore is not a function"

I have no idea how to fix this; as I was expecting it to just work.

Comment: What dependencies did you add for Firebase, and how (if in any way) did you import them into your code?

Comment: I have firebase installed as a node package and ran firebase init, after which I installed the hosting and firebase real-time database.

Comment: The Realtime Database and Firestore are two separate databases, and the SDK for one does not give you access to the other. --- Also: instead of describing what you've included, please edit your question show exactly how you included them (e.g. package.json, import statements, etc).